# How would I loop around the alphabet?

Tags: java

This is a bit more trickier than I thought..

I am creating a java program that is encrypted:

the input is 'a' and shift the letter by 5 which goes to 'f'

which is simple in ASCII but when I get to the letter z i want the program to loop back       around to 'a' and start over if that makes sense just i have no idea where to start!

Comment: i mean i have no where to start on that loop

Comment: You should google `caesar cipher java`.  Also google `Java Modulo`.

Answer (score 3):

The key is modulus division:

```
char c;
c = (char)((c - 'a' + 5) % 26 + 'a');
```

`c - 'a'` gives you the number of the letter `0-25`, which is then shifted up by 5 and the remainder after dividing by `26` is then added to `'a'` to give up back the character for the letter.

Answer (score 3):

Use mod `%` operator.

```
char translated = (char) ('a' +  (charOriginal -'a' + 5) % ('z' - 'a' + 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here it is :

```
public char encrypt(char c)
{
    return Character.isLowerCase(c) ? (char)((c - 'a' + 5) % 26 + 'a') : (char)((c - 'A' + 5) % 26 + 'A');
}
```

I've edited my post, now it checks lower/upper case.

If you don't and minus 'a' for uppercase, it won't work. For example, encrypt('Y') would have returned '^' instead of 'D'.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
/**
 * Shifts a letter 5 letters, if the char is a letter,
 * other wise (if a number or symbol) just returns the char.
 * Jumps back to 'a' or 'A' when it goes past 'z' or 'Z'.
 */
public char shift5(char letter) {
    char letterToReturn = letter;
    if(letterToReturn >= 'a' && letter <= 'z') {
        // letter is lowercase
        letterToReturn = shiftLetter(letterToReturn , 5);
    } else if(letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z') {
        // letter is uppercase
        letterToReturn = shiftLetter(letterToReturn , 5);
    }
    return letterToReturn;
}

/**
 * Shifts a letter to the next letter the specified amount of times.
 * Jumps back to 'a' or 'A' when it goes past 'z' or 'Z'.
 */
public char shiftLetter(char letter, int amountToShift) {
    char letterToReturn = letter;
    for (int i = 1; i <= amountToShift; i++) {
        letterToReturn ++;
        if(letterToReturn == (char)((int)'z' + 1) {
            // letter has gone past 'z', so change to 'a'
            letterToReturn = 'a'
        } else if(letterToReturn == (char)((int)'Z' + 1) {
            // letter has gone past 'Z', so change to 'A'
            letterToReturn = 'A'
        }
    }
    return letterToReturn;           
}
```

This code handles lowercase, uppercase, and characters that aren't letters.

Comment: `public char shift5()` is a bit inflexible if you ask me.  I mean your already giving the ability below to shift by `amountToShift` why not follow that pattern everywhere?